# How to apply CSS style to Quarto output

Tags: css, output, chunks, quarto

I would like to apply a style to Quarto chunk output.

The first thing I made was to embed some CSS properties in a class `.output` in the Quarto document and then referenced it with :

````
```{r class.output="output"}
```
````

It worked, but I think it's not very efficient because I have to write it within each doc.

So I wrote a class `.output` with some CSS properties in a **custom.scss** file, but now

````
```{r class.output="output"}
```
````

doesn't work.

So where and how have I to declare it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a CSS style file to define CSS properties for quarto chunk output should suffice unless you want to build a custom theme (and in that case, you should use SCSS)

So write the CSS properties for a class selector in a `styles.css` file and use `css` YAML key to refer to this `styles.css` from a quarto document file.

**style.css**

```
.output {
  color: green;
  background-color: black;
}
```

**quarto-doc.qmd**

````
---
title: "Output-style"
format: 
  html:
    css: styles.css
---

```{r}
#| class-output: output

x = "hello quarto"
print(x)
1 + 1
```

You can add options to executable code like this

```{r}
#| class-output: output

2 * 2
```
````

---

[image: styled chunk output]

---

Now for the case of SCSS, to refer to a scss file, you need to use `theme` yaml key instead of `css`.

**custom_style.scss**

```
/*-- scss:rules --*/

.output {
  color: green;
  background-color: black;
}
```

**quarto-doc.qmd**

````
---
title: "Output-style"
format: 
  html:
    theme: output_style.scss
---

```{r}
#| class-output: output

x = "hello quarto"
print(x)
1 + 1
```
````

And the output is similar as the above.

Comment: Wow, that'a so simple :) I've tried a lot of solutions, but not this one. Thanks !