Changing the font in different sections of a Quarto document (HTML and PDF)
I need to create a document where different blocks of text have different fonts and font size. So for example something like.
---
title: "My Document"
mainfont: Latin Modern Roman
---

This section is in the normal Latin Modern Roman font. 

::: {.special_font_1}
This text is in a Gentium font
:::

Some more in the regular font

::: {.special_font_2}
Yet more text, but in an Arial font.
:::

Final text in normal Latin font.

Now I was wondering if I can do this kinda thing using CSS, or if
this would not work. I don't really want callouts, though I am using
the callout syntax in the example above. Or is it better to use some HTML tag or something?
I want to make sure that the output in HTML and PDF will use the same
formatting and fonts.
I am also not clear on how to setup the CSS settings to set the font in
quarto. Would I do something as above, like .special_font_1 { font-family: Gentium },
or is something more required.

for CSS, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74026514/how-to-apply-css-style-to-quarto-output For PDF export you either need to change the LaTeX template or choose a PDF engine that understands HTML/CSS

@mb21 so just wanted to confirm, would this approach work for setting different fonts for different sections. So creating the CSS and such and setting the PDF engine should actually produce the desired output right.

Yes, it will probably require a bit of work and manual testing to get the layout just as you want it, but it will work.
